# Java Swing HiDPI solution for icons - SVG and runtime scaling with Batik? Precompiled PNGs?

Tags: java, swing, svg, batik, hidpi

I want to make the graphics (icons, logo etc.) of an existing **Java Swing** application look better on **HiDPI** displays with a scale factor larger than 1.0, e.g. my notebook with 14" display and Windows 10 (scale factor 1.5). At the moment, the application uses PNG images, with one resolution per image, e.g. 16x16 pixels for icons. On JButtons etc. these icons look horrible when they are scaled up by Java.

My current idea (**A**) to solve that problem (see [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56546454/2052584)] and [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76175224/2052584)] for credits):

1. Replace PNGs with **SVGs**.
2. Include **Apache Batik** in the Swing desktop application (~ 4 megabytes of new JAR dependencies just for that, ughh).
3. Use Batik to rasterize the SVGs **at runtime** to multiple `BufferedImage`s, one for each scale factor (1.0, 1.25, 1.5, ...) to be supported.
4. Put the `BufferedImage`s (e.g. 16x16, 20x20, 24x24, ...) into a standard `BaseMultiResolutionImage`.

A slightly different idea (**B**) might be:

3. and 4.: Instead: Extend `AbstractMultiResolutionImage` and overwrite `getResolutionVariant` to rasterize just the requested `destImageWidth`/`destImageHeight` pixel size using Batik (and cache the result with width/height as cache key). This way, any requested `destImageWidth`/`destImageHeight` could be provided exactly. This might be useful, as there seem to be some rounding effects causing dest width or height to differ by 1 or 2 pixels from what I'd expect.

Both approaches above require Batik (and its transitive dependencies) as a runtime dependency / to be included in my client distribution. And I'm like: *Do I really want that just because of some simple icons?!* (= just eye candy)

Therefore, idea **C**: On my dev system, I might use `rsvg-convert` or Inkscape to "precompile" different resolution PNGs from a source SVG (e.g. 16x16, 20x20, 24x24, ...). Then I include the PNGs (not the source SVG) in my application and build a `BaseMultiResolutionImage` just from the precompiled PNGs. This approach offers the huge advantage of not needing Batik. But it's more manual work and not as flexible.

**Question:** Is there maybe a best practice approach or a pure Java solution (maybe in Java 17..20...?) for this as supporting HiDPI seems to be a very common thing? Or what is your solution for this problem?

Comment: Maybe something more like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56618089/java-swing-hidpi-scaling)

Comment: For my applications, I use fonts for icons (like Font Awesome). I have my own library that will create a multi resolution image based on the font name and character.

Comment: @MrSnrub you can start by looking at https://jiconfont.github.io/

Comment: For non-interactive svg files there are also more lightweight alternatives to Batik e.g. [jsvg](https://github.com/weisJ/jsvg) (Disclaimer: I’m the author of jsvg)

Comment: Font icons is a nice idea, many websites use custom fonts for icons. Your approaches are reasonable too. Rasterising or loading only required resolutions will save some memory, you won't store images until they're needed. Converting SVG to PNG will save you from a runtime dependency, yet, as you mentioned, this approach requires more work at build time (or manual work).